# How to make remove display none to this div container in post meta box?

Tags: metabox

I am adding meta box via add_meta_box hook but it is not showing in the admin panel, I double check the source code and it seems hidden because of this line:

```
<div class="postbox-container" id="postbox-container-2" style="display: none;">
```

These are all my attempts to remove this display:none but all are not working:

a.) Using CSS like:

```
#postbox-container-2 {display:block;}
```

b.) Using jQuery like:

```
$('#postbox-container-2').css('style','');
```

OR

```
$('#postbox-container-2').show();
```

OR

```
$('#postbox-container-2').css('display','block');
```

OR

```
$('#postbox-container-2').removeAttr()('display');
```

How to make that div appear? Thank you for any tips.

Comment: have you tried all these possibilities in console?

Comment: Yes..It is not working..It is very odd.

Comment: You got any errors? Use jQuery instead of $ (WordPress load jQuery in no-conflict mode). Does jQuery('#postbox-container-2') return any element?

Comment: No errors, I have it working. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick, in jQuery:

```
    //get page title
var edit_title_page=$("html head title").text();

//Confirm if this is right Edit page

if (edit_title_page.indexOf("Edit Form") >= 0) {
    $('#postbox-container-2').removeClass("postbox-container");
    $('#postbox-container-2').css('width','100%');
    $('#postbox-container-2').css('float','left');
    $('#mymetaboxID').show();

}
```

It will first check for edit page title, if it's on the right page, remove the post-box container containing the display none, then apply a new css styling.

Finally show the meta box added using add_meta_box, this works for me.